# Install package dependency that has no binary version

Tags: r, packrat

I am trying to set up a *packrat* project but it keeps failing because one of the packages (installed from GitHub) depends on a package that doesn't currently have a binary version on CRAN. This is the error message I receive:

```
> remotes::install_github("BroVic/raampGBV")
Downloading GitHub repo BroVic/raampGBV@master
Skipping 1 packages not available: naijR
Installing 114 packages: DBI, RSQLite, ... 
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/Admn/project/packrat/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/3.6.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

   package ‘naijR’ is available as a source package but not as a binary


  There are binary versions available (and will be
  installed) but the source versions are later:
        binary source
digest  0.6.23 0.6.24
stringi  1.4.4  1.4.5
callr    3.4.1  3.4.2
ps       1.3.0  1.3.1

Error: Failed to install 'raampGBV' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) package ‘naijR’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.6.2)
```

Again, to be clear, `raampGBV` exists only on GitHub (it's a project-specific package) while `naijR` is on CRAN. When I try to install `raampGBV` on its own, the `naijR` source package is downloaded and installed from CRAN without any issue. But when attempted via packrat, it fails.

Answer (score 2):

According to NEWS for R 3.6.2:

> For a Windows or Mac OS X binary package install, install.packages()
>   will check if a source package is available on the same repositories,
>   and report if it is a later version or there is a source package but
>   no binary package available. This check can be suppressed: see the
>   help page.

Upon examining the *Binary packages* section of `?install.packages()`, it is evident that the `type` parameter is what is used to control the behaviour referred to in the quote above. The default argument for `type` in `install.packages` is `getOption("pkgType")`, which in my case returned `"win.binary"`. This is how the issue was fixed:

```
oldOpt <- getOption("pkgType")
options(pkgType = "both")

remotes::install_github("BroVic/raampGBV")

options(pkgType = oldOpt)
```

The dependencies are now properly installed in the `packrat` library.